# Comparison of lazy and strict evaluations in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, matrix, lazy-evaluation

I implemented the Winograd algorithm on Haskell and tried to speed up the algorithm due to strict calculations. In this I succeeded, but I completely did not understand why, adding strictness, it starts to work faster. Since my code for this algorithm is large enough, I wrote two small functions that demonstrate this problem.

```
module Main where
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Matrix as M

import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Exception
import System.Clock
import Data.Time

matrixCtor x y size = M.matrix size size $ \(i,j) -> x*i+y*j

group v s = foldl (\acc i ->acc + V.unsafeIndex v i * V.unsafeIndex v (i+1)) 0 [0,2..s-1]

size = 3000 :: Int

testWithForce :: IO ()
testWithForce = do
  let a = matrixCtor 2 1 size
  evaluate $ force a

  start <- getCurrentTime

  let c = V.generate size $ \j -> M.getCol (j+1) a
  evaluate $ force c
  let d = foldl (\acc i ->acc + group (V.unsafeIndex c i) size) 0 [0,1..(size-1)]
  evaluate $ force d

  end <- getCurrentTime
  print (diffUTCTime end start)


testWithoutForce :: IO ()
testWithoutForce = do
  let a = matrixCtor (-2) 1 size
  evaluate $ force a

  start <- getCurrentTime

  let c = V.generate size $ \j -> M.getCol (j+1) a
  let d = foldl (\acc i ->acc + group (V.unsafeIndex c i) size) 0 [0,1..(size-1)]
  evaluate $ force d

  end <- getCurrentTime
  print (diffUTCTime end start)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  testWithForce
  testWithoutForce
```

In the implementation of the algorithm, the matrices are computed before use, just like here. In the function `testWithForce` I calculate the value `c` before it is used. In this case, the function `testWithForce` works faster than the function `testWithoutForce`. I got the following results:

```
0.945078s --testWithForce
1.785158s --testWithoutForce
```

I just can not understand why strictness in this case speeds up the work so much.

Comment: It think it's due to your use of `foldl`; any thunks present in the computation of `c` are magnified due to the the laziness of `foldl`. Play around with using `foldl'` instead.

Comment: @chepner unfortunately, it did not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pardon the non-answer, but make sure to control for GC: it appears that the second function may be burdened with the GC from the previous one, thereby inflating the difference.

I can reproduce what you're seeing:

```
$ ghc -O3 --make foo.hs && ./foo
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( foo.hs, foo.o )
Linking foo ...
1.471109207s
2.001165795s
```

However, when I flipped the order of the test, the result was different:

```
main = do
  testWithoutForce 
  testWithForce

$  ghc -O3 --make foo.hs && ./foo
1.626452918s
1.609818958s
```

So I made `main` GC between each test:

```
import System.Mem

main = do
  performMajorGC
  testWithForce
  performMajorGC
  testWithoutForce
```

The forced one is still faster, but the difference was massively reduced:

```
1.460686986s
1.581715988s
```

Comment: Yes .. Apparently the code I submitted does not contain an algorithm problem ...
Because in the algorithm with control GC is still a solid difference. For example, for matrices 500x500 the time is as follows: 1.81 s and 622.84 ms