# Performance of lazy and strict evaluations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, matrix-multiplication

I implemented the Winograd algorithm on Haskell and, trying to improve it, decided to make it more strict. I did this, but I do not understand why it started to work faster. [Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714703/comparison-of-lazy-and-strict-evaluations-in-haskell) I asked a similar question, but posted not quite correct code.

Since that code does not show a problem, I post the code completely.

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Matrix as M

import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Exception
import System.Clock
import System.Mem
import Data.Time

matrixCtor :: Int -> Int -> Int -> M.Matrix Int
matrixCtor x y size = M.matrix size size $ \(i,j) -> x*i+y*j

winogradLazy :: M.Matrix Int -> M.Matrix Int -> M.Matrix Int
winogradLazy a b = c
  where
    n = M.nrows a
    p = M.ncols a
    m = M.ncols b


    -- Translate into vectors, since indexing in matrices takes longer.
    -- Matrix b is also transposed
    a' = V.generate n $ \i -> M.getRow (i+1) a
    bt' = V.generate m $ \j -> M.getCol (j+1) b

    rows = V.generate n $ \i -> group $ V.unsafeIndex a' i
    cols = V.generate m $ \j -> group $ V.unsafeIndex bt' j

    group x = foldl (groupHelper x) 0 [0,2..p-1]
    groupHelper x acc i = let
                            x1 = V.unsafeIndex x (i)
                            x2 = V.unsafeIndex x (i+1)
                          in
                            acc - x1 * x2

    c = M.matrix n m $ \(i,j) ->
          let
            a = V.unsafeIndex rows (i-1) + V.unsafeIndex cols (j-1)
            b = wsum (V.unsafeIndex a' (i-1)) (V.unsafeIndex bt' (j-1))
          in
            a + b


    wsum r c = foldl (wsumHelper r c) 0 [0,2..p-1]
    wsumHelper r c acc i =  let
                              x1 = V.unsafeIndex r (i)
                              x2 = V.unsafeIndex r (i+1)
                              y1 = V.unsafeIndex c (i)
                              y2 = V.unsafeIndex c (i+1)
                            in
                              acc +(x1+y2)*(x2+y1)


winogradStrict :: M.Matrix Int -> M.Matrix Int -> M.Matrix Int
winogradStrict a b = c
  where
    n = M.nrows a
    p = M.ncols a
    m = M.ncols b

    -- Translate into vectors, since indexing in matrices takes longer.
    -- Matrix b is also transposed
    a' = V.generate n $ \i -> M.getRow (i+1) a
    bt' = V.generate m $ \j -> M.getCol (j+1) b


    rows = V.generate n $ \i -> group $ V.unsafeIndex a' i
    cols = V.generate m $ \j -> group $ V.unsafeIndex bt' j


    group x = foldl (groupHelper x) 0 [0,2..p-1]
    groupHelper x acc i = let
                            x1 = V.unsafeIndex x (i)
                            x2 = V.unsafeIndex x (i+1)
                          in
                            acc - x1 * x2

    c = a' `deepseq` bt' `deepseq` M.matrix n m $ \(i,j) ->
          let
            a = V.unsafeIndex rows (i-1) + V.unsafeIndex cols (j-1)
            b = wsum (V.unsafeIndex a' (i-1)) (V.unsafeIndex bt' (j-1))
          in
            a + b

    wsum r c = foldl (wsumHelper r c) 0 [0,2..p-1]
    wsumHelper r c acc i =  let
                              x1 = V.unsafeIndex r (i)
                              x2 = V.unsafeIndex r (i+1)
                              y1 = V.unsafeIndex c (i)
                              y2 = V.unsafeIndex c (i+1)
                            in
                              acc + (x1+y2)*(x2+y1)



lazyTest :: IO ()
lazyTest = do
  let a = matrixCtor 2 (-1) 500
  let b = matrixCtor 2 (-3) 500
  evaluate $ force a
  evaluate $ force b
  start <- getCurrentTime
  let c = winogradLazy a b
  evaluate $ force c
  end <- getCurrentTime
  print (diffUTCTime end start)


strictTest :: IO ()
strictTest = do
  let a = matrixCtor 2 (-1) 500
  let b = matrixCtor 2 (-3) 500
  evaluate $ force a
  evaluate $ force b
  start <- getCurrentTime
  let c = winogradStrict a b
  evaluate $ force c
  end <- getCurrentTime
  print (diffUTCTime end start)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  performMajorGC
  lazyTest
  performMajorGC
  strictTest
```

in the strict version before computing the matrix `c`, I do the following:

```
a' `deepseq` bt' `deepseq`
```

and because of this I get the following results

```
2.083201s --lazyTest
0.613508s --strictTest
```

Comment: Did you try [profiling?](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html)

Comment: @YotamOhad yes, but I got almost same call stacks. Only different percentages of time for some internal functions.